# Word for red flags / warning signs?

Tags: coding-standards, code-reviews

When reading about best practices and code reviews, I have come across a word/phrase that people on forums have used to describe code that should be a warning sign that the programmer may have missed something or made a mistake.

A sample sentence would have gone something like this: "Often if you see a single if statement with 10 ands/ors, it is a ***_*____**, though in certain cases it can be correct."

What is this word? I want to include this in a code review document I am writing.

Comment: Hm... http://memegenerator.net/instance/13262772

Comment: Why aren't the terms "red flag" or "warning sign" sufficient?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

["Code smell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) is probably the word you're looking for:

> In computer programming, code smell is any symptom in the source code of a program that possibly indicates a deeper problem.

Comment: I'd shy away from using the term "code smell" in a formal document, however. Terms such as "red flag", "warning sign", "indicator" or "X is indicative of Y" are more professional and more readily to be accepted/understood by non-programmers.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - if you're talking about specific pieces of code, then you obviously aren't talking to non-programmers. "Code smell" has an accepted meaning within the profession, I see no reason not to use it.